# Not able to loop through a generic Iterate function

Tags: c#

I am trying to loop through an integer array using C# Iterators. The program below loops through the non-generic Iterator but not through the generic iterator. I am unable to figure out the problem.

```
namespace SampleCSApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var output = new int[10];

        ParallelLoopResult LoopResult = 
        Parallel.For(1, 10, (int i, ParallelLoopState loop) =>
            {
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    loop.Break();
                    return;
                }
                output[i] = Compute(i);
            });

        long CompletedUpto = 10;
        if (!LoopResult.IsCompleted && LoopResult.LowestBreakIteration.HasValue)
            CompletedUpto = LoopResult.LowestBreakIteration.Value;

        string format = string.Format(CompletedUpto == 10 ? "Ran to Completion" : "Completed upto:{0}",CompletedUpto);
        Console.WriteLine(format);

        int index = 0;

        // This does not work.
        foreach (var i in Iterate<int>(() => 0, i => i < output.Length, i => output[i], i => i++))
            Console.WriteLine("output[{0}]:{1}", index++, i);

         // This works.
         foreach(var  i in Iterate(output))
            Console.WriteLine("output[{0}]:{1}", index++, i);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Iterate<T>(Func<T> initialize, Func<T, bool> condition, Func<T, T> body, Func<T, T> update)
    {
        for (T i = initialize(); condition(i); i = update(i))
            yield return body(i);                
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> Iterate(int[] output)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
            yield return output[i];
    }

    private static int Compute(int i)
    {
        return i * i;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the postincrement is the problem?

If your function returns i++, will it not return i then post increment the unshared variable?

ie change it to

```
i => i + 1
```

Does that help?